# Max read depth issue when sending objects to WCF service

Tags: wcf

I am getting the below exception while sending objects to the WCF service, could anyone help me out to resolve this issue.

Exception:
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:xxxx(class object). The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of xxxxx.xx.xxx.xxxx(class). The maximum read depth (200) has been exceeded because XML data being read has more levels of nesting than is allowed by the quota. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxDepth property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 2, position 59349.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Inner Exception: 
The maximum read depth (200) has been exceeded because XML data being read has more levels of nesting than is allowed by the quota. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxDepth property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 2, position 59349.

I have tried by setting the below readerQuotas in bindings both in client and server

```
<readerQuotas maxDepth="200" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
```

My Service Configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="Service">
        <endpoint address="Service" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="IService"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/Service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

My Client Configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:50259/Service.svc/Service"
        behaviorConfiguration="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
        contract="IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Also, I have added maxRequestLength in httpRuntime both in client and service config

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" maxRequestLength="2147483646"/>
</system.web>
```